# Why do my users' downloads randomly stall in IE?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I have downloads that are triggered by a redirect in an iframe.

1. user clicks the "download" button
2. our JS fetches the download URL from the server (it's a timing-out url so it has to be done this way)
3. the iframe is redirected to the download url, which has content disposition of attachment, so the browser starts the download without changing the location of the page.

this works well for all users and browsers... except some IE users.

I've tried to reproduce the problem and here's what I've come up with:

- if the "save or open" dialogue boxes are clicked through quickly, the download always works
- if the "save or open" dialogue boxes are clicked through slowly (like 10-20 seconds) the downloads sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. i haven't been able to find a pattern.

Here's what it looks like when it gets stuck:

[image]

The issue is not from the link timeout on S3 -- my experiments above are well within the time window.

What could be causing these sporadic download failures?

**update**

Server logs suggest that the downloads are being completely sent to the user.

Comment: Normally the download dialog shows how much data has been downloaded, is this the same each time it hangs?  (this is related to @ixe013 answer)

Comment: @Robert nope, it's not consistent between failures. it has different amounts of progress in each failure.

Comment: If it works in other browsers, can you see any differences in IE's traffic with Wireshark?

Answer (score 6):

I did some tests downloading the [LLVM test suite](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/test-suite-3.1.src.tar.gz), a 78 Megs file using IE 9 in Windows 7. The downloads starts when you click the link. Internet Explorer does not wait for you to confirm or cancel. IE saves the bytes to your download directory in a file named fizzbuz.*partial*. IE will catch up with your choice by either renaming the file when its done or deleting it if you cancel.

It could be a timing problem or an HTTP problem.

**Timing problem**

Is it possible that another process opens the file, maybe even locking it ? Maybe a overzealous anti-virus or real-time backup software ? Chances are the close and rename operation (which must take place since the server sent the whole file) goes something like this :

1. Write the last, valid bytes to the fizzbuzz.*partial* file
2. Close the file
3. Rename the file

What if a process grabs the file for exclusive read between 2 and 3 ? Maybe that application makes some changes to file like writing to an alternate NTFS stream which are confusing to IE ?

Keep in mind that browser plug-ins are also notified of the end of the download. Another kind of timing problem could be caused by a plug-in that [monitors the download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136550%28v=vs.85%29), and seeing it end, does some operation. That operation could fail or never return on some occasions.

Try to reproduce the problem without any anti-virus running (a better test than just whitelist the file) and without any browser plug-ins loaded.

**HTTP problem**

The server and client must agree on the way to end the connection. You must either :

1. Close the connection at the end of the transfer
2. Specify the length of the download

It is hard to debug this from a distance, but if at all possible, capture a network trace of the download and look for these clues :

1. The Content-length header is absent or maybe off-by-N (the browser will wait forever for N byte(s) that will not come) ?
2. Does each client have the same proxy configuration ?
3. Is the non-working clients downgraded to HTTP 1.0 ? (There is a setting named "always use http 1.0 through proxy"

From your screen shot, it looks like the browser was not able to compute the estimated time of arrival but there is no correlation between that and the download.

Comment: I'm thinking the delay causes IE to let its receive window fill and then hang waiting for more input to arrive.

Comment: Possible, but my network traces show no difference in the download process with regards to waiting on the user. Since the server sends the whole thing, I take it that the receive window is always full, give or take a few millisecods of latency every now and then.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how IE handles it, but in other browsers while you choose where you want to store the file the download has already started. What's the timeout of your download URL? Have you tried setting it higher? Does it work more than once? (if not, check your log for failed access attempts).
Good luck.

PS: if nothing works, [try this](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/).

Comment: I thought that might have something to do with it too, but 1) if it starts ahead of time, then it is still only accessing it once 2) even if it somehow does something clever/stupid that ends up accessing it twice, the url will still work for multiple accesses within the time limit, which is 1 minute -- well within the timespan of my tests.

Comment: IE also starts the download while you're choosing what to do with it.

Comment: This is correct.  You are simply missing the trigger, whatever it may be, that tells you that the download completed.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE?
IE8 misbehaves sometimes if you don't decide what to do with downloads before it completes...

If the server logs that data was sent to client/browser than the next thing to investigate are proxy and browser.

And your screen-shot actually looks like the download dialogue while selection has NOT yet been made. Is there a selection screen somewhere in the background?

Comment: I took the screenshot after making the selection and the selection windows were gone. Could you elaborate on "misbehaves sometimes"?

Comment: I encountered the situation when IE8 "forgot/lost track" of downloaded file when the save/open dialogue was not actioned for a long time [hours in my case]. It may be not relevant but is still the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `cache-control: max-age` to a value greater than 0. I've noticed that IE can screw up like this on content that's set to expire immediately (ie, by using no-cache).

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate on "screw up like this"?

Comment: ping -- any more info on this?

Comment: i'm only going from issues I encountered in IE6 some years ago, not sure if relevant to new IE versions. The issue was simply that a download set to no-cache via http headers may not actually be saved to disk. Presumably IE deletes the download before it completes but then fails to realise this and still attempts the default open/save action with a file that no longer exists. I could see how that might also lead to stuck progress (it's bad news deleting a file you're still writing to or using a handle to a deleted file).